# Serialization third-party classes with Simple XML (org.simpleframework.xml)

Tags: java, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have decided to use [Simple XML serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) and was stucked with basic problem. I am trying to serialize `java.util.UUID` class instance as final field in this small class:

```
@Root
public class Identity {
    @Attribute
    private final UUID id;

    public Identity(@Attribute UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    } 
}
```

[Tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters) shows how to serialize third-party objects by registering converters like this:

```
Registry registry = new Registry();
registry.bind(UUID.class, UUIDConverter.class);
Strategy strategy = new RegistryStrategy(registry);
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

serializer.write( object, stream );
```

appropriate converter for UUID is pretty simple:

```
public class UUIDConverter implements Converter<UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
       return new UUID.fromString(node.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, UUID value) throws Exception {
       node.setValue(value.toString());
    }
}
```

But this simple code just didn't work for me, during serialization objects with UUID fields was thrown exception **Transform of class java.util.UUID not supported**.

I have tried something something similar with custom `Matcher` (which was not in tutorial) that works for me:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister(new MyMatcher());

serializer.write( object, stream );
```

and `Matcher` class looks like this:

```
public static class MyMatcher implements Matcher {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Transform match(Class type) throws Exception {
        if (type.equals(UUID.class))
            return new UUIDTransform();
        return null;
    }
}

public class UUIDTransform implements Transform<UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID read(String value) throws Exception {
        return UUID.fromString(value);
    }
    @Override
    public String write(UUID value) throws Exception {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Is custom Matcher always recommended practice for streaming third-party classes?
- In which case I can use Converter?
- Are there any better tutorials/examples for Simple XML out there?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using the Convert annotation and the AnnotationStrategy with your converter? Did that work?

Comment: Very same exception with AnnotationStrategy. Similar class with `java.net.URL` field instead of UUID is serialized ok with custom converter. There is built-in support for serialization of URL class inside Simple XML by URLTransform class.

Comment: It looks like Convert<T> is only for customizing serialization of already supported classes, for unknown-for-Simple classes (for example `java.util.UUID`) is necessary create appropriate Transform<T> class and use it with custom Matcher.

Comment: I removed `static` for it to work

Comment: Sorry for `static`, this example was only inner class in tests. Glad to see that my humble post is always relevant :-) I don't use Simple XML anymore, I have to live with JAXB

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have to answer by myself again :-)

Advice from Niall Gallagher, project leader of Simple XML, from support-list:

> "You could use either a Converter or a Transform. I would say 
>       for a UUID a Transform with a Matcher would be the easiest option."

So, I use `Transform<T>`/`Matcher` and satisfied with it. This does not alter the fact that the `Converter<T>` does not work for me :-)

Comment: Very useful question and (self) answer :-) ! Helped me on my application!

Comment: This was way more helpful than the "documentation" for Simple XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have the answer to this.

```
Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
```

should register the converter and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit aold but my chance i came to the same exception.

The actual issue is the use of the @Attribute annotation. If instead of @Attribute
you put @Element the exception does not appear and the converter is used for the serialization.

I guess it will then depend on which annotation you used that you should create a Converter or use the Marker-Transform solution. Although i do not know if this is the intendent behaviour.