# Converter for Joda-Time `DateTime` object to String in `org.simpleframework.xml` ("Simple XML Serialization" library)

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jodatime, simple-framework

How to build a converter for the `org.simpleframework.xml` libary?

I am using the [Simple XML Serialization library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) (`org.simpleframework.xml` package) from [SimpleFramework.org](http://www.simpleframework.org/).

I want [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects to be serialized as an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string such as `2014-07-16T00:20:36Z`. Upon re-constituting the Java object, I want a DateTime to be constructed from that string. The [documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) does not really explain how to build a converter.

I know it has something to do with a [`Transform`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html) and a [`Matcher`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/index.html?org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html). In the [`MythTV-Service-API`](https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythTV-Service-API) project, I found implementations of both [Transform](https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythTV-Service-API/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mythtv/services/api/converters/JodaDateTimeTransform.java) and [Matcher](https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythTV-Service-API/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mythtv/services/api/converters/JodaDateTimeMatcher.java). But I have not determined how to put it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may choose between two approaches, as discussed in this similar Question, [Serialization third-party classes with Simple XML (org.simpleframework.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3626208/642706):

- Converter
- Transform

I do not know the pros and cons of each in comparison. But I do know how to implement the Transform approach. For that, read on.

## Transform Approach

Three pieces are needed:

1. An implementation of the [Transform interface](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html).
2. An implementation of the [Matcher interface](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Matcher.html).
3. A [RegistryMatcher](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/RegistryMatcher.html) instance where the Transform implementation is mapped to the data-type it handles.

All three of these are a part of the [transform package](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/package-summary.html).

I suggest putting your implementations in a "converters" package in your project.

### Transform Implementation

Your Transform implementation may look like this.

This implementation here is a simplistic. It assumes you want the output to be the default ISO 8601 string generated by a DateTime’s [`toString`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString()) method. And it assumes every text input will be compatible with the default parser in a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor. To handle other formats, define a bunch of [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instances, calling the [`parseDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime(java.lang.String)) method on each one in succession until a formatter succeeds without throwing an [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html?is-external=true). Another thing to consider is time zone; you may want to force the time zone to UTC or some such.

```
package com.your.package.converters.simplexml;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.simpleframework.xml.transform.Transform;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 *
 * © 2014 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for such usage and its consequences.
 */
public class JodaTimeDateTimeTransform implements Transform<DateTime>
{
    //static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( JodaTimeDateTimeTransform.class );

    @Override
    public DateTime read ( String input ) throws Exception
    {
        DateTime dateTime = null;
        try {
            dateTime = new DateTime( input );  // Keeping whatever offset is included. Not forcing to UTC.
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            //logger.debug( "Joda-Time DateTime Transform failed. Exception: " + e );
        }
        return dateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String write ( DateTime dateTime ) throws Exception
    {
        String output = dateTime.toString();  // Keeping whatever offset is included. Not forcing to UTC.
        return output;
    }

}
```

### Matcher Implementation

The Matcher implementation is quick and easy.

```
 package com.your.package.converters.simplexml;

import org.simpleframework.xml.transform.Transform;
import org.simpleframework.xml.transform.Matcher;

/**
 *
 * © 2014 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for such usage and its consequences.
 */
public class JodaTimeDateTimeMatcher implements Matcher
{
    @Override
    public Transform match ( Class classType ) throws Exception
    {
        // Is DateTime a superclass (or same class) the classType?
        if ( org.joda.time.DateTime.class.isAssignableFrom( classType ) ) {
            return new JodaTimeDateTimeTransform();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Registry

Putting these into action means the use of a registry.

```
RegistryMatcher matchers = new RegistryMatcher();
matchers.bind( org.joda.time.DateTime.class , JodaTimeDateTimeTransform.class );
// You could add other data-type handlers, such as the "YearMonth" class in Joda-Time.
//matchers.bind( org.joda.time.YearMonth.class , JodaTimeYearMonthTransform.class );

Strategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
Serializer serializer = new Persister( strategy , matchers );
```

And continue on the usual way with a serializer that understands the Joda-Time type(s).